# Propositional calculus-Valuation of a group of propositions

Tags: propositional-calculus

I've encountered these two statements below, and I fail to understand why one of them is true and the other isn't. Let $X_1,X_2$ be groups of propositions,and $Z_1,Z_2$ be their satisfying groups of valuation then:
$Z_1 \cap Z_2$ satisfies $X_1 \cap X_2$ (is false according to the text book),the other statement is $Z_1 \setminus Z_2$ satisfies $X_1 \setminus X_2$ (which is true according to the text book). Every counter argument I tried to come up with also counters the "true" statement so I'm lost and would gladly use some help.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks,I'll read that later.

Comment: What textbook ?

Comment: Local one written by our professor, it might be false therefore I'm trying to get answers from the internet too just to make sure.

Comment: Without further details, IMO you are right: the first is clearly false. A *tautology* is satisfied by every valuation; thus, every tautology must belong to both $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: That's what I had in mind, thank you for validating me.